# Magento Source code

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento2

I am provided with a user name and password of Magento 2 template where I can access the admin panel online.
But my intention is to get access to source code in order to change the menu and some other sliders.

How to get to the source code of the template?

Comment: ask the person that provided you with a username and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you are bit new. Now to change the slider or menus you can do them using both admin panel or source code depending upon how the site has been coded. Since you only have back end access you cannot get the source code at the moment. You can request your site administrator for the code and once you have it , you can go to **root/app/design/frondend/[your-package]/[your-template]/template/page/html/header.phtml** and see if you can see the menu items. If not then search for and cms syntax you can see, if you find one , copy the name and go to backend and in CMS in static blocks and in the identifier copy your name and search. You will get your code, change it and you are good to go. It might sound easy but make sure you have someone who has bit experience or things might go wrong.
To get your current template and package go to **System->Configuration->Design** in that you can find the names.  All the best :)